# python - pandas ffill with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to forward fill the missing rows to complete the missing time-series rows in the dataset.

The size of the dataset is huge. More than 100 million rows.

The original source dataset is as shown below.

```
         col1 col2 col3  col4  col5  col6
0  2020-01-01   b1   c1     1     9    17
1  2020-01-05   b1   c1     2    10    18
2  2020-01-02   b2   c2     3    11    19
3  2020-01-04   b2   c2     4    12    20
4  2020-01-10   b3   c3     5    13    21
5  2020-01-15   b3   c3     6    14    22
6  2020-01-16   b4   c4     7    15    23
7  2020-01-30   b4   c4     8    16    24
```

desired output is as below

```
         col1 col2 col3  col4  col5  col6
0  2020-01-01   b1   c1   1.0   9.0  17.0
1  2020-01-02   b1   c1   1.0   9.0  17.0
2  2020-01-03   b1   c1   1.0   9.0  17.0
3  2020-01-04   b1   c1   1.0   9.0  17.0
4  2020-01-05   b1   c1   2.0  10.0  18.0
5  2020-01-02   b2   c2   3.0  11.0  19.0
6  2020-01-03   b2   c2   3.0  11.0  19.0
7  2020-01-04   b2   c2   4.0  12.0  20.0
8  2020-01-10   b3   c3   5.0  13.0  21.0
9  2020-01-11   b3   c3   5.0  13.0  21.0
10 2020-01-12   b3   c3   5.0  13.0  21.0
11 2020-01-13   b3   c3   5.0  13.0  21.0
12 2020-01-14   b3   c3   5.0  13.0  21.0
13 2020-01-15   b3   c3   6.0  14.0  22.0
14 2020-01-16   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
15 2020-01-17   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
16 2020-01-18   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
17 2020-01-19   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
18 2020-01-20   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
19 2020-01-21   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
20 2020-01-22   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
21 2020-01-23   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
22 2020-01-24   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
23 2020-01-25   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
24 2020-01-26   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
25 2020-01-27   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
26 2020-01-28   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
27 2020-01-29   b4   c4   7.0  15.0  23.0
28 2020-01-30   b4   c4   8.0  16.0  24.0
```

I need to group on `col2` and `col3` to fill the missing time-series rows in `col1` for each of the combinations.

Currently, I have the below code which is working but its extremely slow due to the for-loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def fill_missing_timeseries(subset_df, date_col):
    if subset_df[date_col].dtype != 'datetime64[ns]':
        subset_df[date_col] = pd.to_datetime(subset_df[date_col], infer_datetime_format=True)
    min_date = subset_df[date_col].min()
    max_date = subset_df[date_col].max()

    # generate a continous date column between the min and max date values
    date_range = pd.date_range(start=min_date, end=max_date, freq='D',)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    new_df[date_col] = date_range
    
    # join newly generated df with input df to get all the columns
    new_df = pd.merge(new_df, subset_df, how='left')
    
    # forward fill missing NaN values
    new_df = new_df.ffill()
    return new_df

orig_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['2020-01-01','2020-01-05', '2020-01-02','2020-01-04','2020-01-10','2020-01-15','2020-01-16','2020-01-30'],
                        'col2': ['b1','b1','b2','b2','b3','b3','b4','b4'],
                        'col3': ['c1','c1','c2','c2','c3','c3','c4','c4'],
                        'col4': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                        'col5': [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
                        'col6': [17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
                       })
data = []
grouped_by_df = orig_df.groupby(['col2', 'col3']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
for index, row in grouped_by_df.iterrows():
    subset_df = orig_df[(orig_df.col2 == row[0]) & (orig_df.col3 == row[1])]
    subset_filled_df = fill_missing_timeseries(subset_df, date_col='col1')
    data.append(subset_filled_df)
desired_df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```

Is there any way I can avoid the for-loop and send the whole dataset for creating missing rows and ffill()?

Thanks and Appreciate the help.

Update:
The above code is working but it's too slow. It takes more than 30 minutes for just 300k rows. Hence, I'm looking for help to make it faster and avoid the for-loop.

Comment: unless I'm missing something, I think you have all the pieces you need already! create the missing dates, left join them, and then ffill the nulls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a `resample` on `groupby` would work:

```
(df.set_index('col1').groupby(['col2', 'col3'])
   .resample('D').ffill()
   .reset_index(['col2','col3'], drop=True)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
         col1 col2 col3  col4  col5  col6
0  2020-01-01   b1   c1     1     9    17
1  2020-01-02   b1   c1     1     9    17
2  2020-01-03   b1   c1     1     9    17
3  2020-01-04   b1   c1     1     9    17
4  2020-01-05   b1   c1     2    10    18
5  2020-01-02   b2   c2     3    11    19
6  2020-01-03   b2   c2     3    11    19
7  2020-01-04   b2   c2     4    12    20
8  2020-01-10   b3   c3     5    13    21
9  2020-01-11   b3   c3     5    13    21
10 2020-01-12   b3   c3     5    13    21
11 2020-01-13   b3   c3     5    13    21
12 2020-01-14   b3   c3     5    13    21
13 2020-01-15   b3   c3     6    14    22
14 2020-01-16   b4   c4     7    15    23
15 2020-01-17   b4   c4     7    15    23
16 2020-01-18   b4   c4     7    15    23
17 2020-01-19   b4   c4     7    15    23
18 2020-01-20   b4   c4     7    15    23
19 2020-01-21   b4   c4     7    15    23
20 2020-01-22   b4   c4     7    15    23
21 2020-01-23   b4   c4     7    15    23
22 2020-01-24   b4   c4     7    15    23
23 2020-01-25   b4   c4     7    15    23
24 2020-01-26   b4   c4     7    15    23
25 2020-01-27   b4   c4     7    15    23
26 2020-01-28   b4   c4     7    15    23
27 2020-01-29   b4   c4     7    15    23
28 2020-01-30   b4   c4     8    16    24
```

Comment: Thanks @quanghm ! The approach you suggested worked. Appreciate it.

Comment: The above method works for pandas dataframe. Do you know if the above method can be converted to use with Spark dataframe? There is a pandas-type package for spark called Koalas. Is there any chance, to get the above steps working with spark/koalas dataframe?

Comment: The "new koalas" called pyspark.pandas seems to have that feature: [documentation of feature](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html?highlight=ffill#pyspark.pandas.groupby.GroupBy.ffill)